# comparison not being stored in variable c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have the following line:

```
bool test88 = -1 == -1;
```

However, in visual studio, when I put a line break on the next line and check my locals window, there is no test88 variable (and when I hover over it no value appears)

Why is this?

Comment: In addition, make sure that you add `Console.ReadKey();` to prevent the console from exiting too early to be able to review the result. As Others have said, make sure you are in debug mode and that you have built the latest version of your code.

Answer (score 8):

You are debugging in Release mode. Change your configuration to `Debug` and you will be able to see the value.

Or make sure that you are using `test88` in your code like:

```
Console.WriteLine(test88);
```

and then you will be able to see the value.

In release mode, variable which are not used are optimized away from the compiled code, so that is why you are not seeing the value/variable.

Comment: @pQuestions123, just added that as well, In release mode, variables which are not used in the code are optimized away, since there is no need for them and hence they are not even available in debugging.

Answer (score 0):

If you code is optimized and `test88` is not used anywhere else, then it could be an explanation. 
Check: Properties -> Build -> Optimize code